# PostgreSQL TDS_FDW connection to pull in SQL Server metadata

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, freetds, tds-fdw

Creating a metadata repository in PostgreSQL but am having difficulty with TDS_FDW and attempts to import SQL Server's INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

Using tds_fdw version 2.0.0-alpha.3

When I try to import "master", TDS_FDW produces a syntax error:

```
postgres=# IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA master FROM SERVER sql002 INTO public OPTIONS (import_default 'true');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2: ) SERVER sql002`
```

If I run a test import schema using dbo, it works fine, but INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't exist

What would be a functional way to pull the database and column names from SQL Server into PostgreSQL?  (It's been ages since I was a SQL Server dba)